# Include jQuery into Wordpress template

Tags: jquery, wordpress, web, slideshow

I have a custom made slideshow, which I used jQuery to develop. It works perfect on my local machine, but when I try and transition it to the wordpress server it just will not work...

This is how I link my javascript files:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>       
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/JQueryUI.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/slider.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/gallery.js"></script>
```

And I've also checked that the javascript is working (stuff like alert). But everything related to jQuery doesn't.

Desperately need help. Any hints or links to related tutorials will do. Thanks n advance!

Comment: did you solve this ? how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in your `functions.php` file, not your `header.php`. (and you're adding jQuery twice)

*functions.php:*

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/JQueryUI.js', );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gallery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gallery.js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

You should also note that WordPress enqueues jQuery in [noConflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries), so you'll need [noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) to be able to use `$`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // your code here
});
```

Then you just call `wp_head()` and WordPress will automatically add those javascripts to your page.

Comment: I cannot get what do you mean... In which file do I add the code that you have written, header.php or slider.js???

Comment: `wp_head()` should be before `</head> in `header.php`. Your jQuery stuff in `slider.js`.

Comment: You have just `var ` on line 2 in `gallery.js`. remove it.

Comment: I do have the wp_head() before </head>.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error in gallery.js, however, it dodn't solve it.

Comment: your `JQueryUI.js` does not exist on your server. you need to correct the path

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: [Function Reference/wp head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head), in the **In twentyten theme** example they added a note:

> ```
> /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
>  * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
>  * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
>  * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
>  */
> ```

this just says you need to put the `wp_head();` function just befor closing the `<head></head>`.

so try on putting this line:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

as the last line before closing the `<head>` in you'r site.

and another problem i have seen is that you forgot to end the php lines with `;`

it is very critical !

with the code you gave here, change it with this:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/JQueryUI.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/gallery.js"></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but it didn't help... The fun this with the slider, is that it shows me the first slide, and it doesn't change it...

Comment: can you post a link so i could see the problem?